# Can't find MRO (Microsoft R Open) installation on MacOS, after installation

Tags: r, microsoft-r

Thought I'd give MRO a spin, to see if it speeds up my usage in general.

I can't find the installed R though. Not as a separate, not as an overwrite.

`/usr/local/bin/R` contains `R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"`, which is also the one used by RStudio.

`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/` also only contains 3.4.

The GUI "Microsoft R Open.app" has the description `R 3.3.0 GUI 1.68 Mavericks build`... but it also returns 3.4.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've identified a bug in the installer. Thanks!

Looks like we are not installing the MRO framework files because the package installer is detecting a newer version (CRAN 3.4). We will get this fixed in the next release.

In the meantime, you can work around this by renaming `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4` to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/0.3.4` and reinstalling MRO. Then go ahead and rename it back.

Please note, as a part of the install we update the symlinks to point to our version, so if you would prefer the default R installation to be CRAN 3.4 please do the install in the reverse order or manually update the symlink to Current in the Versions folder.